# Steam isn't opening in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, steam

I have some problems with Steam I am having problems resolving. I had it up and running yesterday, playing games browsing through sales and what not. Today Steam will not even run. When I click on steam or one of my Steam games it just flashes for a few moments then stops. Any idea what the problem might be? I have read other forums but none of them seemed to have a solution for me. When I type steam into the terminal I get this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
[2016-07-08 11:51:28] Startup - updater built Jul  7 2016 20:54:44
SteamUpdateUI: An X Error occurred
X Error of failed request:  BadValue (integer parameter out of range for operation)
```

UPDATE: I uninstalled and purged Steam. After reinstalling I get this:

```
Running Steam on ubuntu 16.04 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libXtst.so.6
libgtk-x11-2.0.so.0
libgdk_pixbuf-2.0.so.0
```

When I hit Enter, it says

```
Fatal Error: Failed to load steamui.so
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on your output can you try this command. You seem to be missing some required library. Try this command to install those missing libraries.

```
sudo apt install libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libgtk2.0-0 libxtst6
```